# appending multipleDIVs to multiple TDs using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, append

I have a TR  with 5 TD's in it.
now I want to add to each of the last 3 TDs a series of divs with data taken from an array:

```
arr=[   
{Div1Data:'text1a',Div2Data:'text2a',Div3Data:'text3a'},
{Div1Data:'text1b',Div2Data:'text2b',Div3Data:'text3b'},
{Div1Data:'text1c',Div2Data:'text2c',Div3Data:'text3c'}  
];
```

so I have

```
var tds=$('td',myTR).slice(2,4);

 how do I addppend the 3 divs to each td to eventually get something like:

<tr>
   <td>foo</td>
   <td>bar</td>
   <td><div>text1a</div><div>text1b</div><div>text1c</div></td>
   <td><div>text2a</div><div>text2b</div><div>text2c</div></td>
   <td><div>text3a</div><div>text3b</div><div>text3c</div></td>
</tr>
```

please note that I would also like to bind a click event to each such div, so I con't want to compose the HTML but rather build the actual elements.

Thanks

Comment: all your elements in the array have same name? is it correct?

Comment: this was just a a typo creating the Q. fixed it, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tds.each(function() {
    var index=0;
    for (var prop in arr[index]) {
        if (arr[index].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            $(this).append($('<div>'+arr[index][prop]+'</div>'));
        }
    }
    index++;
});
```

(sorry about the many edits... brain not working too good this am)

http://jsfiddle.net/WR3GA/12/

Just noticed your note about binding - if you are going to bind right as you create the elements, just assign them to an interim variable

```
    var el = $('<div>'+arr[index][prop]+'</div>');
    el.bind(...);
    $(this).append(el);
```

You could also just use a selector afterwards which is probably easier.

Comment: thanks, so $(this) within .each is the "current element" ? I did not know that I thought you need to get it as a parameter for the function.

Comment: `this` in javascript is not simple or intuitive if you are coming from an object oriented programming language (well really, any other language). It's value depends on context, and the rules are not especially obvious. But more importantly, it can be reassigned by the calling code of any function. jQuery redefines `this` inside the `each` constructor to be equal to the current DOM element in the iteration.

Comment: IMHO `this` is very simple :) its the object that the code containing it (it being the reference to `this`) was invoked as a method of (or within its context). This can be done by actual assignment `o.m=f;o.m();` so `this` within `f` would become `o` or by using `apply` or `call` like `f.call(o,param1,param2...)` or `f.apply(o,params)` both with same effect or `this` within `f` being `o` but without the side effect of adding `f` as an actual method of `o`.
so it turns out thats Jquery invokes the function passed to `each` as a method

Comment: Sorry, I was assuming you weren't familiar with it already, given the question. But most languages don't let you redefine the concept of "my owner" which is why its confusing to many people. And you also forgot the real kicker: "except in a private function defined within another function, in which case "this" is the global object." Just to make things more counterintuitive.

Comment: I was not aware of this exception And I am not actually sure that it IS an exception. do you maybe have some code example for this ?

Answer (score 0):

this is the code I came up:  http://jsfiddle.net/y5TQF/5/

```
for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
{
    var div = $("<div />").html(arr[i].Div1Data);
    div.click(function() { /* click handler */ });
    $('table tr td').eq(3).append(div);
}
```

you can do the same for 4th and 5th td.

Answer (score 0):

you can try : http://jsfiddle.net/rxjNf/1/

```
$(function(){

addContent('Div1Data',2);
addContent('Div2Data',3);
addContent('Div3Data',4);

});

 function addContent(p,tdIndexNumber)
    {
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
    {
      var div = $("<div />").html(arr[i][p]);
      div.click(function() { /* click handler */ });
      $('table tr td:eq('+tdIndexNumber+')').append(div);
    }
}
```

AND This example : http://jsfiddle.net/rxjNf/2/ 
**[Will get each row in table and add content]**